# Selection of cruise FL and semi-circular rule

Tags: flight-planning, easa-regulations, visual-flight-rules, flight-level

Let's assume I am flying VFR from A to B.

B is located north-northwest of A, eg. a direct course would yield a magnetic track of, say, 350°(M). However, some legs of my route are northeastwards, before dog-legging northwestwards, eg. 020°(M) then 340°(M).

In that case, how do I apply the semi-circular rule when selecting a flight level? Would I:

- only consider the location of my destination relatively to my departure, and my route as a whole, and select an even FL+5?
- select my flight level leg-wise, ie. flying at an odd FL+5 in the northeastwards part of the route, then even FL+5 when adjusting westwards?

Answer (score 1):

The selection of a level is based on your aircraft track, so you should always adjust based on the *current leg* not the overall track of origin to destination.

(Highlighting in the following is mine.)

> The VFR rules of flight level and/or altitude selection is the same as IFR ones with adding 500ft to all levels.
>
> The default worldwide semi-circular rule is the East/West orientation of the flight level parity:
>
> - **Your aircraft has track** between 0° and 179°, your flight level or altitude must be odd.
> - **Your aircraft has track** between 180° and 359°, your flight level or altitude must be even

<sub>source: https://wiki.ivao.aero/en/home/training/documentation/Semicircular_rules</sub>